# Convert Access TRANSFORM/PIVOT query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
TRANSFORM Avg(CASE WHEN [temp].[sumUnits] > 0 
                   THEN [temp].[SumAvgRent] / [temp].[sumUnits] 
                   ELSE 0 
              END) AS Expr1
SELECT [temp].[Description]
  FROM [temp] 
GROUP BY [temp].[Description]
PIVOT [temp].[Period];
```

Need to convert this query for sql server

I have read all other posts but unable to convert this into the same

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do with some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : Dont know its just some query written in ms access. and we have to convert the program into php application with sql server 2005!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the equivalent version using the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN sumUnits > 0 
      THEN SumAvgRent / sumUnits ELSE 0 
  END AS Expr1,
  Description,
  Period
  FROM temp
) t
PIVOT
(
  AVG(Expr1)
  FOR Period IN(Period1, Period2, Period3)
) p;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3f83/1)

For instance, this will give you:

```
| DESCRIPTION | PERIOD1 | PERIOD2 | PERIOD3 |
---------------------------------------------
|          D1 |      10 |       0 |      20 |
|          D2 |     100 |    1000 |       0 |
|          D3 |      50 |      10 |       2 |
```

---

**Note that** When using the MS SQL Server `PIVOT` table operator, you have to enter the values for the pivoted column. However, IN MS Access, This was the work that `TRANSFORM` with `PIVOT` do, which is getting the values of the pivoted column dynamically. In this case you have to do this dynamically with the `PIVOT` operator, like so:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Period)
                FROM temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');



SET @query =  ' SELECT Description, ' + @cols + '
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        CASE 
          WHEN sumUnits > 0 
          THEN SumAvgRent / sumUnits ELSE 0 
      END AS Expr1,
      Description,
      Period
      FROM temp
    ) t
    PIVOT
    (
      AVG(Expr1)
      FOR Period IN( ' + @cols + ') 
    ) p ';



Execute(@query);
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3f83/10)

This should give you the same result:

```
| DESCRIPTION | PERIOD1 | PERIOD2 | PERIOD3 |
---------------------------------------------
|          D1 |      10 |       0 |      20 |
|          D2 |     100 |    1000 |       0 |
|          D3 |      50 |      10 |       2 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the response now i get a clear view of what to do with the query. let me do the same and check wether it works the same way or not :)

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud. How would you write this into a CREATE VIEW statement?

Comment: @avguchenko - AFAIK, you can't write this into a view nor a UDF, because of the dynamic sql, but you can however do it inside a stored procedure, it will work fine.

Comment: Just a minor update _without_ using XML: [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0306/66)