# How to write a SQL Query in MS Access to Count different values in same field and group by a Foreign Key

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I currently have this in `MS Access`:

`SELECT ClassID, Count(Component) AS ActiveDuty
FROM tblStudents
WHERE Component = "Active_Duty"
GROUP BY classID;`

It gives me the correct answer which looks like this:

`ClassID ActiveDuty
006-14  14
007-14  12
008-14  8`

But if I want it to look like this what do I need to do?

`ClassID ActiveDuty Reserve National Guard
006-14  14           5          6
007-14  12           9          8
008-14  8            7          18`

I tried using subqueries like this:

`SELECT ClassID, (SELECT COUNT(Component) FROM tblStudents WHERE Component = "ActiveDuty") AS Active_Duty,(SELECT COUNT(Component) FROM tblStudents WHERE Component = "Reserve") AS ArmyReserve,
(SELECT COUNT(Component) FROM tblStudents WHERE Component = "National_Guard") AS NationalGuard
FROM tblStudents
WHERE Component = "Active_Duty"
GROUP BY ClassID;`

But this is the result I get:

`ClassID ActiveDuty  Reserve National Guard
006-14  34            37          29
007-14  34            37          29
008-14  34            37          29`

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and show the subqueries you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MS Access’ wizard to help you make a Crosstab Query for this.  It will generate something like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(tblStudents.[Component]) AS CountOfComponent
SELECT tblStudents.[ClassID], Count(tblStudents.[Component]) AS [Total Of Component]
FROM tblStudents
GROUP BY tblStudents.[ClassID]
PIVOT tblStudents.[Component];
```

Comment: WORKED LIKE MAGIC!! But if there is a way to do it in SQL I would love to know for future reference.

Comment: What if I want to include the count of Gender as well?  So the total number of Males and Females in each Class?

Comment: This is article gives a pretty good understanding of the difference between MS Access' and TSQL's PIVOT:  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953134/convert-access-transform-pivot-query-to-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Adding Gender could be a little more complicated depending on how you want to the table to look.  If you want three dimensional data, someone else is going to have to help you.  =)  But if you don’t mind a 2D solution:

```
TRANSFORM Count(temp.[ComponentGender]) AS CountOfComponent
SELECT temp.[ClassID], Count(temp.[ComponentGender]) AS [Total Of ComponentGender]
FROM (SELECT ClassID, Component & "_" & Gender as ComponentGender FROM tblStudents) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.[ClassID]
PIVOT temp.[ComponentGender];
```